# Is it legal to invest in foreign startups as a non-accredited investor?

Tags: united-states, investing, legal, start-up

If a US person doesn't qualify as an accredited investor. Can he/she still invest in foreign startups (early stage companies based outside the US)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accredited_investor#United_States

Comment: I'm trying to understand the U.S. law regarding the limitations that individuals (people) and U.S. entities have regarding their ability to invest in private companies, as this isn't a limitation in most countries (in most countries you can invest wherever you like being a person). From the SEC's website and from Wikipedia I can understand that in order to invest in private companies (not public) you need to have a yearly income of $200,000 or a net worth of $1M or manage $1M. I was wondering if this restriction applies to all private companies including businesses incorporated outside the US

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The (U.S) "accredited investor" laws apply to investments in the U.S. Foreign countries may or may not have their own laws regarding investment in startups, and if so, the foreign laws apply.

One way around the net worth minimum is to be a member of the management team. "Active" (management) investors don't need to be accredited because they can see what's going on on a day to day basis.

The accredited investor laws apply to the target companies, not to the investors. Basically, a start-up company can't take "other people's money" from a non-accredited investor. But you can invest "your own" money in it if you are a manager.